# How do i connect to a hidden wifi network in kubuntu 13.10?

Tags: wireless, networking, kubuntu, wpa2

I just installed Kubuntu 13.10 on a laptop. I was trying to connect to a hidden Wi-Fi network with WPA2 Security and I noticed there is no way to connect to it from the Network Manager. I can't connect to the internet without Wi-Fi so I can't download any programs to do it and I was wondering if there is a way to connect at all.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your wifi have been recognized by the system, by opening a Terminal, and typing:
`sudo ifconfig -a`

There should be an `eth0`, and an `lo` interface. **And** most importantly, an another, `wlan0`, or similar.
If you are missing the extra plus one interface, we found the problem.

As I said in the comment earlier, you either need a firmware, which the system will automatically download... once you connect to the internet. Or, your wireless card is not supported at all.

**Solution?**
Get some wired internet from somewhere, or even bluetooth tethering could work I guess.
But you can also Google your `$wireless chip` and `linux` keywords in Google.

Answer (score 1):

A useful workaround is: add your network manually to networks list and then in console execute

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan essid myessidname
```

Replacing myessidname (and perhaps wlan0) with your network name/interface

Now it appears in the list and you may connect.